# How to create an enum function that returns a tuple of Ints?

Tags: swift, enums, tuples, func

Good day everybody. I'm creating an `enum` to get the screen resolution when I supply an iDevice type ( the screen size numbers are fake here ).
I have code working when I use no `enum` function, but would rather like to use an `enum` function to keep things clean and together.
The code that I have so far, for using an `enum` function is the following...

```
enum iDeviceType {
    case iPhone(String)
    case iPad(String)
    ...

    func screenSize()->(Int,Int){
        var myModel: (Int, Int)

        switch ????? {
        case .iPhone(let model):
            switch model {
            case "XR" : myModel = (width: 400, height: 612)
            case "6" : myModel = (width: 465, height: 712)
            case "6Plus" : myModel = (width: 465, height: 912)
            ...
            default: myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            }

        case .iPad(let model):
            switch model {
            case "Air 1gen" : myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            case "Air 2gen" : myModel = (width: 405, height: 565)
            ...
            default: myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            }

        default:
            print("not an iOS device")
        }
        return myModel
    }

}

let myModel = iDeviceType.iPhone("XR").screenSize()
print(myModel.height)
```

The last two lines of code is the way I would like to call the `enum` function and get the result back.

What am I missing? I did try `self`, at the question marks, to get the current `iDeviceType`, but can't get it to work.

Any suggestions to make it more clear? I am using Swift 5.

Comment: Thank you vacawama. My next thing to do is that the model (sub)case is also an `enum`, to have it always a valid input, like I did with the `iDeviceType`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with a few modifications.  The key modification is to specify the return type of `screenSize()` as `(width: Int, height: Int)` so that you can unpack the result.

```
enum iDeviceType {
    case iPhone(String)
    case iPad(String)
    case other

    func screenSize() -> (width: Int, height: Int) {
        var myModel = (width: 0, height: 0)

        switch self {
        case .iPhone(let model):
            switch model {
            case "XR" : myModel = (width: 400, height: 612)
            case "6" : myModel = (width: 465, height: 712)
            case "6Plus" : myModel = (width: 465, height: 912)
            default: myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            }

        case .iPad(let model):
            switch model {
            case "Air 1gen" : myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            case "Air 2gen" : myModel = (width: 405, height: 565)
            default: myModel = (width: 365, height: 512)
            }

        default:
            print("not an iOS device")
        }
        return myModel
    }
}

let myModel = iDeviceType.iPhone("XR").screenSize()
print(myModel.height)
```

> 612

---

**Making `screenSize` a computed property:**

Since you're not passing anything to `screenSize()`, consider making it a computed property:

change:

```
func screenSize() -> (width: Int, height: Int) {
```

to:

```
var screenSize: (width: Int, height: Int) {
```

And then access it like this:

```
let myModel = iDeviceType.iPhone("XR").screenSize
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still learning, and my next step was to start using a var instead of a func. So, now I have learned two things in one go.

Comment: My next thing to do/learn is that the model (sub)case is also an enum, to have it always as a valid input, like I did with the iDeviceType. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can use  `enum`s for `iPhoneModel` and `iPadModel` defined inside of `iDeviceType`.  Enum cases can't start with a number, so you might have them start with an underscore:     `enum iPadModel {
        case _Air_1gen
        case _Air_2gen
    }` then you'd use it like this: `let myModel = iDeviceType.iPhone(._XR).screenSize`

Comment: Done, but looks a little bit ugly. I will do a redo/refactor the original one, with just one `enum` set with `Strings` like `"iPhone 6"`, `"iPad Air 1 gen"` and so on. Then I only have to supply at one place/time the `deviceModel` type.